# owl carousel stacking items - is there a limit of size how many items?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

the owl carousel after 8 or some items started to stack the items

[image]

### HTML

```
 <div id="news-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme col-12" style="display:block; margin: 1px">

            @foreach ($manchetes as $manchete)
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border: 1px solid brown; margin: 2px">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm" data-id="{{$manchete->id}}" data-tema="{{$manchete->tema}}"
                    data-tit="{{ $manchete->titulo }}" data-desc="{{$manchete->descricao}}">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2 style="background: gold;" class="my-0 font-weight-normal">
```

### Javascript

```
 $('#news-slider').owlCarousel({
        center: false,
        loop: true,
        margin: 5,
        items: 3,
        pagination: true,
        navigationText: true,
        dots: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 1500,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        scrollPerPage: true,
        animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
        animateIn: 'flipInX',
        stagePadding: 5,
        smartSpeed: 1650,
        dotsEach:3,
        nav: true,
```

It´s very strange that in the element inspector he is showing the elements as inside the same `div` like in the picture:

[image]

Any help?

More ackward behaviours...

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the margin would start to push items that don't fit the container, thus pushing everything afterwards. What happens when you remove the margin: 5?

Comment: hey @GrandIQ, thanks for the suggestion but no changes... keep stacked... only that the boxes are now withouth any margin between them...I setted `margin: 0`

Comment: Check the HTML output your template generates. Perhaps something is messed up in there, some closing element missing somewhere or something like that.

Comment: @misorude... yes, I´ve just found what was happening... some rich text format was comming from the database with html formating embedded and filling the content inside the div´s and creating tables and so on... so I´ve used the `strip_tags` function... and this was enough to solve the issue...